# Clone AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment into another application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I find it very easy to clone an environment within the same application so I have different versions but is there a way to clone an environment into a different application?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is needed what versions of what?

Comment: Ok so I have two applications. I have one setup with two environments. Both apps needs / use Amazon Linux 64bit with Node.js. When I try to create a new application, I get some or the other error but the one application I have running works just fine so I would like to simply copy the configuration into the new application.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?